# Desktop menu disappears after mobile menu is activated/deactivated and resized

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

The site is a responsive site and this is how you duplicate the issue:

1. Load website at desktop width (nav element loads fine).
2. Resize to tablet or mobile size (menu is converted to mobile-style drop-down menu with three bar icon.
3. Open and close the mobile nav menu (It is set to display:none).
4. Now, when you resize to desktop width, the nav bar remains set to display: none.

I am aware that I could solve the issue by creating two menu bars and just applying separate ids to them, but I wanted to see if anyone had a solution to allow me to only have to maintain one menu.

The HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
        <li id="information">
            <a href="#">Why We're Different</a>
        </li>
        <li id="services">
            <a>GPA Services</a>
            <ul id="servicesmenu">
                <li><a href="#">HealthWatch</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ClaimWatch</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Administrative Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Marketing and Sales</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Specialty Services</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="login"><a>Login</a>
            <ul id="loginmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Employers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Brokers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Providers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#menu-icon").click(function() {
        $("#menu").slideToggle(); 
  });
    $("#services").click(function() {
        $("#loginmenu").slideUp();
        $("#servicesmenu").slideToggle();
    });
    $("#login").click(function() {
        $("#servicesmenu").slideUp();
        $("#loginmenu").slideToggle();
    });
    $('html').click(function() {
        $("#loginmenu").slideUp();
        $("#servicesmenu").slideUp();
    });
    $('#login, #loginmenu, #services, #servicesmenu').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Or you can view a test version of the page here (note: the page/images have not been optimized for load time, so the sizes of some of the images make the load times a little long):

http://test.digital-scorpion.com/gpa/index.php

Comment: its because once you toggle off it will make the #menu display:none  and then you make the browser size big, it got stuck with display none; Using 2 different menu for this problem can be better solution, without headache

Comment: Yeah, I know the reason it is happening, I'm just trying to figure out a way to fix it. I considered having the page reload on resize, but that is bad web practice. I would just have two separate menus before doing something like that.

Comment: of you can do if the browser size fits your desktop media query, you can simple make it display block. I think your desktop css will work 1200px and higher

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try and add this to your stylesheet:

```
@media screen and (min-width:1199px) {
       #menu { display:block !important; }
}
```

Comment: Wow! This was it! Now that I see it, it seems so obvious! Lol. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This lets you not bother with the JS, just overwrites no matter what. Simple and clean, nice. +1 for you.

Comment: using !important is not a good practice but here it is a good solution +1

Answer (score 2):

When the button is clicked, it is changing the location of the `ul` that holds the menu. When it is clicked again to hide the menu, it changes everything back, but adds a `display:none`. You need to remove that from your JS file.

Since you are using a custom function `slideToggle` which includes most of the individual actions, it'll be difficult to remove. You could recreate your own function and call that instead, or just call all the individual actions. You could also just let it happen and then reset it to `display:block;`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#menu-icon").click(function() {
        $("#menu").slideToggle().show(); 
  });
  ... JS Continues ...
```

**EDIT:**

You might have an issue with timing. You want the `.show()` to be applied last and overwrite the `.hide()` that is part of the .`slideToggle()`. If you place it as a completion function, it won't fire until after the other is complete.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#menu-icon").click(function() {
        $("#menu").slideToggle(function() {
              $("#menu").show(); 
        });
  });
  ... JS Continues ...
```

Comment: Sorry to say that this did not have the intended effect. Thanks anyway, though!

Comment: Since your edit... This may work, but the solution above was a little more simple for my purposes. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to +1 any answers that work and are useful, and give the checkmark to the one you end up using.

Answer (score 0):

Sample HTML

```
<div class="navbar-container">
     <ul class="nav group pull-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Activities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Administration</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
     </ul>
     <a href="#" id="pull">Main Menu</a>
</div><!--navbar container-->
```

Jquery Function

```
  $(function() {
     var pull = $('#pull');
     menu     = $('.navbar-container ul');
     menuHeight = menu.height();

     $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         menu.slideToggle();
      });

     $(window).resize(function(){
       var w = $(window).width();
       if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
           menu.removeAttr('style');
     }
     });
    });
```

Styles

```
#pull {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  padding:5px;
  margin:0px auto 0 auto;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#5a504c;
  background-color:#e7e5e2;
}
```