# Disappearing page content after resizing menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently making responsive website.

Every time after clicking *menu bar* to resize it, *main-content* dissappears completely. I think that it might be coused by height argument of some element in CSS or adding flexbox arguments but I checked it many times and I can not find a reason.

Html:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>SimpleReports</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/global.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/general.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="header">
            <div class="logo"><a href="#">X<span>X</span></a></div>
        </div>
        <a class="mobile" href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>MENU</span></a>

        <div id="container">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li>
                        <a class="selected" href="index.html"><span><i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>Panel analityczny</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="tge.html"><span><i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>TGE</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="transakcje.html"><span><i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>Transakcje</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="wiadomosci.html"><span><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>Wiadmości</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="uzytkownik.html"><span><i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>Użytkownik</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="title">
                XXXX
                </div>
                <div class="main">
                    <div class="widget">
                        <div class="title">x1</div>
                        <div class="chart">asdas sadasd asdas</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget">
                        <div class="title">x2</div>
                        <div class="chart"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget">
                        <div class="title">x3</div>
                        <div class="chart"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget">
                        <div class="title">x4</div>
                        <div class="chart"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.mobile").click(function(){
        $(".sidebar").slideToggle('fast');

    });
    window.onresize = function(event){
        if($(window).width() > 375){
            $(".sidebar").show();
        }
    };
});
```

CSS:

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Lato';
}
span + span {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
body {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.logo {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 14px;
    margin-left: 10px;

}
.logo a {
    size: 1.6em;
    color: #f2f2f2;
}
.logo a span {
    font-weight: 300;
}

div#header {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #077fad;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    div#container {
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    /* komputer */
    .sidebar {
        width: 250px;
        background-color: #044762;
        float: left;
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    ul#nav {
    }
    ul#nav li {
        list-style: none;

    }
    ul#nav li a {
         color: #f2f2f2;
         display: block;
         padding: 20px;
         font-size: 0.8em;
         border-bottom: 1px solid #022431;
         -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
         -moz-transition: 0.2s;
         -o-transition: 0.2s;
         -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
         transition: 0.2s;
    }
    ul#nav li a:hover {
        background-color: #022431;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .mobile {
         display: none; 
    } 

    ul#nav li a.selected {
        background-color: #022431;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .main-content {
        padding-top: 40px;
        margin-left: 260px;
        width: auto;
        overflow: scroll;
        height: auto;
    }
    /* main content styles */
    .main-content .title {
        background-color: #eef1f7;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #b8bec9;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #333;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    /* main box container */
    .main {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .widget {
        width: 45%;
        height: 250px;
        margin: 15px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .widget .title {
        background-color: #eef1f7;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #dfe4ec;
        padding: 10px;
        border-top-left-radius: 6px;
        border-top-right-radius: 6px;
        color: #617085;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    /* tablet */
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    .main-content {
        margin-left: 100px; 
    }
    .sidebar {
        width: 80px;
    }
    ul#nav li a span:nth-child(2) {
         display: none;
    }
    ul#nav li a i {
         font-size: 1.6em;
         text-align: center; 
    }
    .widget {
        width: 40%;
    }
    }
    /* telefon */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 375px){
    .mobile {
         display: inline-block; 
         position: absolute;
         margin-top: 50px;
         padding: 15px;
         text-align: left;
         background-color: #044762;
         font-size: 1em;
         width: 100%;
         height: 50px;
         color: #fff;
    } 
    .sidebar {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 100px;
    } 
    ul#nav li a span:nth-child(2) {
         display: inline-block;
    }
    .main-content {
        margin-left: 0px;
        padding-top: 90px;
        height: auto;
        }
    .widget {
        width: 100%;
    }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 376px){
    .sidebar {
        height: 100%; 
        } 
    .main-content {
        height: 100%; 
    }
    }
```

What is interesting, after adding `<p> test </p>` element under *sidebar*, *main-content* is visible but there are some problems with paddings.
Do you know what might be causing a problem?

How it looks before click:

[image: before]

And after (there is nothing under):

[image: after]

And with added `<p> test </p>` under *sidebar*
[with test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s21Gx.png)

Comment: Isn't happening for me when I click on the `.mobile` link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRpdrN

Comment: looks to be because your header bar has `position:absolute`. add padding or a margin to the other elements of about `50px` and it should fix your issue. Or, alternatively, just change the header back to `position:relative;` (or just delete that style declaration)

Comment: I see you are using font-awesome, are you also using any other CSS frameworks? could help your process quite a bit so you don't have to write so much code.

Comment: @Jhecht i added those 50 px in every element but it is not a problem. Everything started with boxes in main-content section.

Comment: Is the issue that the menu is sitting on top of the content, instead of pushing it down? This goes back to you should get rid of the `position:absolute` because that's sort of what it does.

Comment: @Jhecht I got rid of  `position:absolute` but main-content still dissappears after resizing menu bar

Comment: http://codepen.io/jhechtf/pen/NdXqgO?editors=0010 does this fix the issue you are describing?

Comment: No, that code I took from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328444/desktop-menu-disappears-after-mobile-menu-is-activated-deactivated-and-resized] to solve different issue (dissappearing menu bar) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this should fix your issue. The problem was that in your CSS media queries you were setting styles in multiple places that overlapped and caused some weird functionality. The big issue with your slider menu was that the `.sidebar` menu was set to have the property `float:left`, which meant that the reason your content was being hidden off screen was because it was sitting just off screen since your `.sidebar` was 100% of the screen's width.

There were two options: either remove `float:left` from `.sidebar` or add `clear:left` into the `.main`. I chose to remove the `float` because there were no other breaking changes when I tested it on the codepen I linked you in the comments.

Other than that, some minor visual fixes for paddings / margins.

Happy Coding

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.mobile").click(function() {
    $(".sidebar").slideToggle('fast');

  });
  window.onresize = function(event) {
    if ($('.sidebar').not(':visible') && $(window).width() > 375) {

      $(".sidebar").show();

    }
  };
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Lato';
}
span + span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.logo a {
  size: 1.6em;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}
.logo a span {
  font-weight: 300;
}
div#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #077fad;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div#container {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* komputer */

.sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #044762;
}
ul#nav li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul#nav li a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #022431;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
ul#nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #022431;
  color: #fff;
}
.mobile {
  display: none;
}
ul#nav li a.selected {
  background-color: #022431;
  color: #fff;
}
.main-content {
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 260px;
  width: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: auto;
}
/* main content styles */

.main-content .title {
  background-color: #eef1f7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b8bec9;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 18px;
}
/* main box container */

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.widget {
  width: 45%;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.widget .title {
  background-color: #eef1f7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dfe4ec;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  color: #617085;
  font-weight: 400;
}
/* tablet */

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .main-content {
    margin-left: 100px;
  }
  .sidebar {
    width: 80px;
  }
  ul#nav li a span:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
  }
  ul#nav li a i {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .widget {
    width: 40%;
  }
}
/* telefon */

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
  .mobile {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #044762;
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .sidebar {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  ul#nav li a span:nth-child(2) {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .main-content {
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 90px;
    height: auto;
    clear: left;
  }
  .widget {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 376px) {
  .sidebar {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .main-content {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <div class="logo"><a href="#">X<span>X</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="mobile" href="#"><span><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>MENU</span></a>

<div id="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li>
        <a class="selected" href="index.html"><span><i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>Panel analityczny</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="tge.html"><span><i class="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>TGE</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="transakcje.html"><span><i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>Transakcje</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="wiadomosci.html"><span><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>Wiadmości</span></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="uzytkownik.html"><span><i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><span>Użytkownik</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="title">
      XXXX
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="widget">
        <div class="title">x1</div>
        <div class="chart">asdas sadasd asdas</div>
      </div>
      <div class="widget">
        <div class="title">x2</div>
        <div class="chart"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="widget">
        <div class="title">x3</div>
        <div class="chart"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="widget">
        <div class="title">x4</div>
        <div class="chart"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost! It works great with resizing menu, but now on big screen (desktop and tablet view) main-content section is under sidebar - like it was added some padding equal to sidebar height

Comment: Thank you very much :) I was trying to solve this for 2 days... I would try not to override code in the future :)

Comment: Just remember that a `min-width:300px;` and a `max-width(500px)` in a media query have `200px` where their style rules overlap. I'd recommend looking into a responsive CSS framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) where a lot of what you are doing has been done before _and_ tested thoroughly.

Comment: OK, I will do my research :) I am quite new in website coding (Actually I have just started with this project for my studies) so every advice is good advice. BTW can you recommend some litrature or frameworks to create simple analytics webapp connected to database?

Comment: Everybody starts somewhere, so no worries. What sort of server would be running this app, and what database engine?

Comment: Server - I don't know yet I have to read about it first. Database probably SQL or access but I would start with simple excel file :)

Comment: Without knowing those two things, it's hard to recommend anything. There's _tons_ of server-side languages/configurations and _tons_ of database engines. Popular servers are Apache, Node, NgInx, IIS (windows) (not necessarily in any order). Popular Server-side languages are Ruby, Node, some variety of .NET, Javascript (Node environment), & PHP. And Popular databases are Oracle, MySQL, MS Sql Server, Mongo DB (used heavily with Node apps), PostgreSQL.

Comment: [DB-Engines Ranking](http://db-engines.com/en/), [W3Tech - Server Side Languages](https://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/programming_language/all), and [W3Tech - Web Servers](https://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/web_server/all) for some usage references.

Comment: Thanks @Jhecht, I would start with reading about these. It is good place to start from :)