# Mobile navigation bar disappears on desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make a sidebar navigation that is static on desktop and collapsed on mobile devices. The problem is that when I press the toggle button on mobile, the navbar stays toggled and is not visible on desktop. Here is my code below:

HTML

```
<div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">
    <div class="bg-light" id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar-heading"><img class="heading-img" src="./images/logo.png"></div>
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush nav-group nav-items">
        <a href="index.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light nav-single"> <img class="nav-img" src="./images/home.svg">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light nav-single"> <img class="nav-img" src="./images/settings.svg">Settings</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light nav-single"><img class="nav-img" src="./images/exit.svg">Exit</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#menu-toggle{
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 768px){
  #menu-toggle{
    display: unset;
  }
}
```

JS

```
  <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
  </script>
```

Is there a way to detect that it's resized and remove the "toggled" text

Answer (score 0):

i've experienced such issue in the past and i solved it by just adding an !important attribute to the css styling for tablets and desktop mode

for example

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 750px){
  #navigation{
     display: initial !important;
  }
}
```

the !important attributes makes the navigation always visible on desktop mode even after toggling the button in mobile mode.

A question similar to this has been asked in the past, you can check out the link below

[link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328444/desktop-menu-disappears-after-mobile-menu-is-activated-deactivated-and-resized)